# How do I escape from a Snippet? (Vb.Net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, code-snippets

In C# when I am done entering the fields of a snippet, I can hit Enter to get to the next line. What is the equivalent Key in VB?

Edit: I prefer not to use the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow... I sure hope they improve this soon.

Meanwhile, in case anyone cares, I created an additional replacement field ($Enter$) at the end of my custom snippet. This allows me to [tab] through the fields and then type [DownArrow] [Enter] when I reach the end of the list.

Something like....

```
private _$PropertyName$ As $PropertyType$
Public WriteOnly Property $PropertyName$() As $PropertyType$
     Set(ByVal value as $PropertyType$)
          _$PropertyName$ = value
     End Set
End Property $Enter$
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the key, but I use *right-click -> Hide Snippet Highlighting*.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there isn't one- VB.NET snippet support lags behind that of c#

There's no support for

- $end$ in the snippet
- ClassName() or other functions
- snippet hints.

And there's field tab issues as well - in c# you only tab through *unique* fields.  In vb.net you tab through all.

In short, using snippets n vb.net is not as fun.

Answer (score 0):

At any point while you're editing a snippet, you can use the up/down arrow keys to get out of it. Or have I misunderstood what you're trying to do?

Comment: In C#, hitting Enter takes you to the End of the Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the down arrow key? Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

For the record, VB snippets do support tooltips (hints) and help URLs.